# Compare Google sheet dates to Google Calendar Event date

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Matching dates from Sheet and Google Calendar is always false, how can I format the two dates to compare?

I've attemped to format the dates even if they look exactly the same it comes back false.

```
var Sheet_StartDate =  Spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1).getValue();
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('####');
var event = calendar.getEventById(eventId); 
var calendar_StartTime;

try {
  // Get all day event
  calendar_StartTime = event.getAllDayStartDate();          
}
catch (e) {

  //Multi-day event
  calendar_StartTime = event.getStartTime();

}


if (calendar_StartTime === Sheet_StartDate )
{
 //This comes back false 

}
```

Comment: Try comparing Date().valueOf() or Date().getTime().  See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function compareDates() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dt=new Date(sh.getRange(1,1).getValue());
  var Sheet_StartDate_value=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();//This removes the time portion
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('####');
  var event = calendar.getEventById(eventId); 
  dt=new Date(event.getAllDayStartDate());
  var calendar_StartTime_value=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();      
  if(calendar_StartTime_value == Sheet_StartDate_value ) {
    //This will come back true if in fact they are the same date
  }
}
```

You can also use Date().getTime()